CMake Error: At least one entry of URL is a path (invalid in a list) when building Flutter app on Windows
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
Building Windows application...
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:2771 (message):
  At least one entry of URL is a path (invalid in a list)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:3681 (_ep_add_download_command)
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (ExternalProject_Add)


CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/pdfx/windows/DownloadProject.cmake:171 (message):
  CMake step for pdfium failed: 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/pdfx/windows/CMakeLists.txt:20 (download_project)


Error: Unable to generate build files

I've tried cleaning the build and running the build command again, but the issue persists. It seems to be related to the pdfx plugin and its dependency on pdfium. I'm not sure how to resolve the issue with the URL path in ExternalProject.cmake.
